# Coordinate Geometry Locus

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Let $(x,y)$ be any arbitrary point on a curve and the distance from origin of the point $(x,y)$ has been defined as $d$ such that $$d=\max(|x|,|y|)$$ and $$d=k$$ such that $k$ is a non-zero positive constant.

then what would be the locus of the point $(x,y)$.

I tried to solve the question using basic properties of absolute values.

$$|x| \le k ; |y| \le k$$
$$\Rightarrow -k \le x \le k ; -k \le y \le k $$

According to this must be a square formed by the lines $$x=k; x=-k; y=k; y=-k$$
But my book mentions the answer to be a straight line. Can anybody help me over this issue?

Comment: The answer is wrong, and it is indeed a square.

Comment: When you say, at the beginning, "$(x,y)$ is an arbitrary point on a curve" (an not in the plane), what is this curve ?